# How do I convert an ES6 import to a require?

Tags: node.js

I have some js code that wants to be imported using ES6 import syntax

```
import crazymodule from 'crazymodule';
```

How do I convert this to nodejs `require` syntax?

I've tried:

```
const crazymodule = require('crazymodule')
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Javascript require vs require .default](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43247696/javascript-require-vs-require-default)

Answer (score 0):

I'd been googling for the answer for this for a while and didn't hit a good answer so I made this one to help future peeps using the same search terms as me.

That answer is you need to have .default on the end of the require line:

```
const crazymodule = require('crazymodule').default
```