# How can I upgrade new react app version without hard refresh?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I Upgrade my **react app** and when I want to release it, clients can't see my changes until they do a hard refresh `(Ctrl+F5)`.

How can I upgrade it without need to hard refresh by clients?

Comment: If you're using webpack you could hash your bundle filename: https://webpack.js.org/guides/caching/

Comment: [HMR](https://webpack.js.org/concepts/hot-module-replacement/) might lead to an interesting solution. I have never seen anyone doing this in production. [This SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24581873/what-exactly-is-hot-module-replacement-in-webpack/24587740#24587740) also explains well.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't use webpack or systemjs,  you can pull version number at the end of the file url

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="app.js?20190826"></script>
```