# laravel-mix produces empty (0 bytes) .css files WITHOUT dynamic imports and .extract

Tags: javascript, laravel, webpack, laravel-mix

I'm getting empty .css files without using .extract and import()
When I'm running `npm run dev`

My webpack.mix.js:

```
let mix = require('laravel-mix');
mix.js('resources/assets/js/app.js', 'public/js').sourceMaps()
    .js('resources/assets/js/admin.js', 'public/js').sourceMaps()
    .sass('resources/assets/sass/app.scss', 'public/css')
    .sass('resources/assets/sass/admin.scss', 'public/css');

mix.copyDirectory('resources/assets/img', 'public/img');
```

The strange thing here is that if I remove one of .js mixes it works. For example this works:

```
mix.js('resources/assets/js/app.js', 'public/js').sourceMaps()
    .sass('resources/assets/sass/app.scss', 'public/css')
    .sass('resources/assets/sass/admin.scss', 'public/css');
```

this also works:

```
mix.js('resources/assets/js/admin.js', 'public/js').sourceMaps()
    .sass('resources/assets/sass/app.scss', 'public/css')
    .sass('resources/assets/sass/admin.scss', 'public/css');
```

But I need to generate admin.js (or app.js) after that. Which is not very handy. 
Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

My environment is:

- Laravel Mix Version: 5.0.0
- Node Version: 11.0.0
- NPM Version: 6.10.3
- OS: macOS High Siera  / Ubuntu 18.04 LTS

I'm sure that I have no dynamic imports, because I'm upgrading from laravel-mix v.3. But also I checked my code. And if I have dynamic imports, none of my examples will work.

EDIT: 
I found that the problem is in my admin.js file which imports:

```
import router from './router'
```

and  in /router/index.js there is another import:

```
import routes from './routes.js'
```

and the problem seеms to be in routes.js file which looks like that:

```
const routes = [
    {
        path: '/',
        component: resolve => require(['../views/admin/dashboard/dashboard.vue'], resolve),
        meta: {
            title: "Dashboard",
        }
    },
];
export default routes
```

But, I can't still explain where is the dynamic import here?!?!?
Or how this works:

```
mix.js('resources/assets/js/admin.js', 'public/js').sourceMaps()
    .sass('resources/assets/sass/admin.scss', 'public/css');
```

Comment: Then `admin.js` is using dynamic imports

Comment: If you claim that it's WITHOUT dynamic imports, wouldn't it be wise to include your JS files code in the question?

Comment: @Saly3301, yes it seems that problem is in file related to admin.js but how then this works: mix.js('resources/assets/js/admin.js', 'public/js').sourceMaps()
    .sass('resources/assets/sass/admin.scss', 'public/css'); ?

Comment: @Saly3301, sorry for that, I provided code.

Answer (score -1):

I changed this:

```
component: resolve => require(['../views/admin/dashboard/dashboard.vue'], resolve),
```

to this:

```
component: require('../views/admin/dashboard/dashboard.vue').default,
```

and now it works. This article was very helpful: [What exactly is Hot Module Replacement in Webpack?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24581873/what-exactly-is-hot-module-replacement-in-webpack)